# Correct syntax for disabling a radio button after it was chosen

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

is it possible to disable a radio button? after a user chooses one of the radio buttons , i don't want them changing answers so i want to disable the radio button, i've used

`radioButton.setEnable(false)`

but still it's able to choose other radio buttons.

What is the correct syntax in disabling a radio button after it was chosen?

Comment: Should also be tagged swing/awt.

Comment: Surely setEnabled(false) will only affect that radio button: not others. Which buttons are you calling setEnabled(false) on?

Comment: Still choose more radio buttons? Sounds like you want check boxes.

Comment: uhmm i have 2 radio buttons, true and false i've used the setEnable(false) to both but still after choosing one button , like for ex: i chose the true but after that i can still choose it over and over

Comment: have you grouped your radiobuttons in to a group...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 JRadioButton b1 = new JRadioButton("");
 b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     if ("disable".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
      b1.setEnabled(true);
       } else {
        b1.setEnabled(false);
       }
    }
    });
```

Comment: it worked now ! thanks a lot ^_^ haha i made a mistake the first time i used the syntax.. thank you very much :)

Comment: @user3360927 Glad to help. if you liked it, please, mark it as answered

Comment: @rpax im just wondering, can i also use that to multiple radio buttons?

Comment: @user3360927 of course. But you must be very careful about the logic of enabling/disabling.